# PHP and HTML multi file upload with progress bar

Tags: php, css, html, apc

I have a website that allows multiple files to be uploaded using HTML5 multiple setting. I use a PHP script to validate the files and upload them. Using only PHP and HTML/CSS I would like to create a progress bar for the file (or files) being uploaded. How can I achieve this? I know PHP can use APC to get file upload info, but how can that be incorporated for multiple files being uploaded?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
     div#banner_left {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0%;
       left: 0%;
       width: auto;
     }
     div#banner_right {
       float: right;
       width: auto;
     }
    </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/structure.css">
</head>
<?php
echo "<div id='banner_right'>Welcome ";
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo "<br><form action='/logout.php'>";
echo " <input type='submit' value='Logout' style='width:216px; font-size: 15px;'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</div><br><br>";
?>


<!-- FILE UPLOAD SCRIPT//-->

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$subject_list = $_POST['subject_list'];
$document_type = $_POST['document_type'];
$uploaddir = "/var/www/rye-high-website/Rye High/uploads/$subject_list/$document_type";
$files=array();
$fdata=$_FILES['rye_file'];
if(is_array($fdata['name'])){
 for($i=0;$i<count($fdata['name']);++$i){
  $files[]=array(
   'name'     => $fdata['name'][$i],
   'tmp_name' => $fdata['tmp_name'][$i],
  );
 }
}
else $files[]=$fdata;

foreach ($files as $file) {
  // uploaded location of file is $file['tmp_name']
  // original filename of file is $file['name']
  $move_file = move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], "$uploaddir/".$file['name']);
}

if ($subject_list == "None") {
   echo '<br><div class="alert">Please Pick A Course Code</div>';
}
if ($document_type == "None"){
   echo  '<br><div class="alert">Please Pick A Document Type</div>';
}
if($move_file){
   echo  '<br><div class="info">File is valid, and was successfully uploaded to: $subject_list folder</div>';
  }
else {
     echo '<br><div class="alert">Upload Failed</div>';
     echo $move_file;
 }
}

?>


<!-- CONTINUE WITH HTTP FORM//-->


<body>
<div id="banner_left">
<img src="/Rye High/images & scripts/logo_ryerson.gif"/>
</div>
<br><br><div class="img">
<img src="/images/logo.png" />
</div><center>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>" method="POST">
Choose Document Type:
<select name="document_type">
<option value="None">Pick Document Type</option>
<option value="Textbooks">Text Books</option>
<option value="Notes & Assignments">Assignment/Notes</option>
</select><br>
Choose Course Code:
<select name="subject_list">
<option value="None">Pick Course</option>
<option value="ACC 100">ACC 100</option>
<option value="ACC 406">ACC 406</option>
</select><br>
Choose file(s) to upload (Max 500MB): <input name="rye_file[]" type="file" id="multiple" multiple />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I appreciate your help,

P.S. I would prefer to avoid using javascript since I'm not familiar with it well enough. PHP and HTML/HTML5 preferred.

Comment: Here's a Jquery plugin supporting multi-file uploads and progressbars you might find it helpful. http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do without JavaScript. You need to manipulate your DOM without refreshing the page (IE canceling the file upload)

Comment: progress bar requires JS. Another plugin you can use : http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You save yourself a lot of struggle if you use javascript to solve the issue! Under is a link to a tutorial, maybe take the best from that one, and search for it on google.

http://www.w3bees.com/2013/10/file-upload-with-progress-bar.html

http://hayageek.com/jquery-multiple-file-upload/

Comment: Im trying to implement the top link you suggested. I opened a new question since it has to do with JSON implementation. Anyways thanks for the links

Comment: The top link works great now, slight javascript error was fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey simonkaspers1, how can i take from the first link the data in html to send in mysql, i need just the filename set in an hidden input with value=filename in an simple <form>?